# How to compare a UILable text (that is linked to a UIPickerView) to an NSString?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uipickerview

So I have a `UILabel` that is linked to the current selected value of a `UIPickerView`.

I also have a button that when pressed calls a method that reads the value from that `UILabel`, compares it with a specified `NSString` and according to that comparison and does or does not perform an action.

```
if (myLabel.text == @"sample text") {
  // code that does something 
}
```

However even though the label text and the text that I compare it to seem identical, it doesn't pass the verification.

I hope that was clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String comparison

```
if([myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"sample text"])
{
//code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, you can't really directly compare string pointers, it almost never works. Instead, you need to use the [isEqualToString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744) method of `NSString`, like this:

```
if( [myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"sample text"] ) {
  // do something
}
```

For more on dealing with strings, specifically comparing them, see [Searching, Sorting, and Comparing Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI) in the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035-SW1).

Comment: Thanks Jason. This is my first question posted on Stackoverflow and I really appreciate the tolerant attitude towards newbies :) A lot more questions coming soon :D